# How to change the display color of the screen on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron, dell-latitude

This is the display color on **Dell Latitude E5470** on **Windows 7**

[image: Dell Latitude E5470]

whereas for **Dell Inspiron 7000 series** on **Windows 10**

[image: Dell Inspiron 7000 series]

The last one is a slight yellowish in color.

On the second machine, I want to have the display color same as that on the first machine.

Please suggest. This is a feature of Windows OS.

Comment: On the Dell Inspiron is probably activated the [Night Light](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-night-light-windows-10-and-how-use-it) setting.

Comment: @spike_66 The *Night Light* setting will add a *red* tint to the display, but his concern is about *yellowish* color.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a Dell *bug*. You can try disabling *Dell Intelligent Display*:

1. Right-click the battery icon found in your taskbar
2. Click *Dell Intelligent Display*
3. A dialog box should open. Uncheck the box before *Dell Intelligent Display*.

[Source](https://www.dell.com/community/General/Dell-Intelligent-Display-AND-Dell-extended-battery-life/m-p/3738510/highlight/true#M614746)